# Get the full dom traversal address of a node, going down from body to the node, without relying on getElementBy or $('jQuery')

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

I'm writing a userscript and I want to get the "address" of a node, like, if the web page is like this:

```
<body>
    <content>
        <a href='/something' name='element I'm interested in'>
    </content>
</body>
```

How do I get the address of `a` (where `a` is a particular `a` element that I know and can point to it manually, or with other regular selectors) so it would give me this: **`body.content.a`** which I can then use in my userscript to perform operations on it like you would on a node gotten by getElementBy() method in javascript.

Obviously the real page would be much more complex and I can't write it all out. Is there a way to get that address either by running jquery or javascript on the page or some browser tool?

Comment: You can't.  DOM nodes are not addressable in javascript with syntax like `body.content.a`.  You can use CSS selectors with `document.querySelectorAll("body content a")` if you know the chain.  If you don't know the chain, then it's not clear what info you're starting with for your question.

Comment: You should show or explain what you've tried so far, then you would be less likely to get downvotes. Otherwise it looks like a reasonable question (especially compared to the majority of new questions asked recently)

Comment: @JK. I'm not sure what to try. Other than googling and coming up with nothing, that is. I guess jfriend00's comment would be the asnwer.

Comment: If you already know the element, then you don't need it's "address".  You can always just get it by the name that you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript if you already have the element in some variable and you want to find it's heirachy then it should be possible just by traversing the nodes parent chain: eg something like

```
function getAddress(element) {
    var address = element.tagName;
    if (element.parentNode) {
       address = getAddress(element.parentNode) + '.' + address;
    }
    return address;
}

// using the above function by
var node = document.getElementById("myFavouriteNode");
var address =  getAddress(node);
```

Note that that "address" in the format you suggested wont actually be usable for finding nodes or anything as per the comments on your question.  You will need to specify how you intend to use the address first.

Comment: I was planning on using it to perform regular operation as you would on a node gotten by getElementBy() method. But that wouldn't be possible right? This would essentially be just a string, right?

Comment: @laggingreflex you're asking this question in loops. You would already have the element to get the so-called *address*. To resolve the address into an element would require more than just the tagName, since you may have multiple elements (nay, subtrees) matching a simple element.element.element address. For a reverse lookup, I would suggest sticking with CSS selectors, or if you want more power, read up on XPath queries, they're probably more in the line of what you're looking for